# how to disable notification bar in all the launched apps from launcher app

Tags: android, launcher, android-notification-bar, kiosk-mode

In my Android launcher home app (4.x), I've disabled "Notification bar/Quick settings" using theme "android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen". Now when my launcher app launches other activities, i want to disable notification bar from launched activities as well. Is this possible? My main goal is to turn the device into Kiosk mode by blocking "settings app" from being launched outside of my launcher app. Any Kiosk experts here?

Comment: I don't think this is possible without creating a custom android image - but I may be wrong.

Comment: some apps are customizing Notification bar in ICS though.

Comment: any luck in achieving this? I am also looking for the same.